# How are software and game templates designed?

Tags: java, c++, software-design

please don't mind my question since I don't know much about software because I come from a web perspective.. For example, in web css is used for the design and appearance

so..

How are the designs, templates, and environments created for software and games made with programs like c++ and java?

Are they designed with the same languges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many facets to developing a game.  Most games consist of the following:

1) A rendering engine.  This is the presentation layer and provides scene-graphs, math, particle effects, post-processing effects, and a whole host of other things.  [Unreal](http://www.unreal.com/) is such an engine.  A good free rendering engine is [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org)

2) A sound engine.  This takes care of processing sound effects (usually handling it in 3D space), and streaming audio.  An excellent free audio-layer is [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx).

3) Video compression/playback (E.g [BINK](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkmain.htm)) if your game requires it.  A free version is [Theora](http://www.theora.org/).

4) Networking.  This is something that might well be written in house, or got off the shelf like the other components, e.g. [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/).

5) Scripting.  It doesn't always make sense to have the entire game written in C/C++/Java.  Sometimes the logic and flow of a level is easier to describe in a scripting language which makes changing it on the fly without recompilation much easier.  Good candidates are [LUA](http://www.lua.org/), [Python](http://www.python.org/) and even [Squirrel](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/).  LUA is used by World of Warcraft for example and is easy to bind to C++.  Civ4 uses Python.

Obviously some or all of these can be written in-house, but it make sense from a cost point of view that if it has been done well already, why bother?  You also need some software to edit your assets ([3D Studio Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=13567410&siteID=123112) for 3D, for example, [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) if you want a good, solid, free package).

Comment: @greyfade, thanks for the clarification.  I have amended the post!

Answer (score 4):

> Are they designed with the same languages?

It depends on how the game developer has decided to do it.

- They could be implemented in (just) the coding language; e.g. C++ or Java.
- They could be implemented in part using some language provided by a standard games engine or framework ... or a more general (non-gaming) graphics / presentation framework ... or some general purpose scripting language (with an embeddable interpreter).
- They could be implemented in part using a game-specific language implemented by the game developer as part of his/her.

Or some combination ...